# JS: Creating a Promise class -- how does function take an arg?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at an implementation of a Promise class (at bottom).  The constructor takes a function, `f`.
So if I have a regular function I want to pass in:

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log("My Func");
}
```

If a Promise looks like this :

```
let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    myFunc();
}
```

then I am confused as to what `f` represents now though in the constructor of the class below.  It appears as though `resolve` is the argument, not a function, `f`.

**Promise Class*

```
class Promise {
    constructor(f) {
         this.onResolves = [];
         this.status = "pending";
         const resolve = value => {
            debugger
           this.status = "resolved";
           this.value = value;
           this.callOnResolves();
         };
         f(resolve);
    }
    callOnResolves() {
         if (this.status === "resolved") {
           this.onResolves.forEach(onResolve => onResolve(this.value));
           this.onResolves.length = 0;
         }
    }
    then(onResolve) {
         return new Promise(resolve => {
           this.onResolves.push(value => resolve(onResolve(value)));
           this.callOnResolves();
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: `f` is the *executor* function `resolve => { myFunc(); }` from `new Promise(resolve => { myFunc(); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f` is the function that you pass to the promise's constructor. It takes a `resolve` parameter, which should eventually be called with the result of the asynchronous work.

Typically, your anonymous function would make use of an api that supports callbacks instead of promises, and in your callback to that api you would call `resolve` to let the Promise know that your asynchronous work is complete.

This is actually how you could implement an asynchronous `sleep` method using `setTimeout`.

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
  });
}
sleep(1000).then(() => console.log(new Date()));
```

Comment: thanks andy.  So what is `f(resolve);` doing then?  Isn't that calling the function passed in with `resolve` argument?

Comment: `f(resolve)` is calling your anonymous function, that is immediately calling `myFunc`, which isn't all that interesting. This Promise construct is usually used to convert callbacks to promises. I've updated my answer to demo how you would convert the `setTimeout` function into an async `sleep` function using a Promise.